# map kit not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

i am working on a map kit that shows all the data extracted from an xml web service .this web service contains 3 variables longitude (lon),latitude(lat), the name of the atm (atmName).the for loop is extracting the data from the Aatm array but the pins are not showing on the map .also my pins are all from the same region thats why i used a default center from the Aatm array with a default value. here is my code 
thank you for helping me in advance :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    Aatm = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    pinArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *url=@"http://192.168.83.1:8080/jeeRestApp-1.0/rest/Atm";
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    parser=[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    parser.delegate=self;
    if ([parser parse]==FALSE){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erreur" message:@"erreur de connection!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    //Setting the approximate region

    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [self.mapview setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    MKCoordinateRegion Myregion;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center1;
    //replace by variable -----------------------------------
    atm=[Aatm objectAtIndex:1];

    center1.latitude=[atm.lat doubleValue];
    center1.longitude=[atm.lon doubleValue];

    NSLog(@"la latitude (defaut) est: %@",atm.lat);
    MKCoordinateSpan span1;
    span1.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    span1.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;

    Myregion.center=center1;
    Myregion.span=span1;

    [mapview setRegion:Myregion animated:YES];

    for(int i = 0; i<=[Aatm count] - 1;i++)

    {
        //CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoord = { atm.lat, atm.lon};

        atm=[Aatm objectAtIndex:i];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D pinLocaton;
        pinLocaton.latitude=[atm.lat doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"latitude est de :%@",atm.lat);
        pinLocaton.longitude=[atm.lon doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"longitude est de :%@",atm.lon);
        MKPointAnnotation *annotation=[MKPointAnnotation alloc];
        annotation.title=atm.atmName;
        NSLog(@"latitude est de :%@",atm.atmName);
        annotation.coordinate=pinLocaton;

        MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]     initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotation1"];
        newAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        newAnnotation.animatesDrop = YES;
        newAnnotation.canShowCallout = NO;
        [newAnnotation setSelected:YES animated:YES];


        [mapview addAnnotation:annotation];
        NSLog(@"annotation added");
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is why the oins are not showing on the map

Comment: You'll need to implement the delegate method `-[mapView:viewForAnnotation:` and create and return the `MKPinAnnotationView` there.

Comment: While I agree that having a local CLLocationManager is kind of pointless, he's not actually using it for anything anyway.

Comment: You're also allocation the MKPinAnnotationView, but never initializing it (with `initWitnAnnotation:reuseIdentifier`)

Comment: After the `setRegion` line and before the `for` loop, please add this NSLog and see what it says: `NSLog(@"mapview = %@", mapview);`.  Does it say mapview is "null"?

Comment: its giving me a null answer . what should i do

Comment: That means the mapview IBOutlet is not connected to the MKMapView control on the storyboard or xib.  You need to connect the IBOutlet (also make sure the map view's delegate outlet is connected as long as you're doing that).

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` something like:

```
-(MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]])
    {
        MKPinAnnotationView*    view = (MKPinAnnotationView*) [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pin"];
        if(!view)
        {
            view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];
        }
        else
        {
            view.annotation = annotation;
        }

        view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        view.animatesDrop = YES;
        view.canShowCallout = NO;

        return view;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll also need to make sure you properly initialize the annotation with `[[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]` instead of just allocating it.  When you create the MKMapView do you set the view controller to be it's delegate?

Comment: And, as @anna mentions above, make sure that the mapView outlet is priorly set up in the storyboard and/or nib.